# How to do hide and show another table when row is clicked in angular 2?

Tags: angular

[I want to do like this in angular 2](https://www.igniteui.com/hierarchical-grid/angular)

Any suggestions without third party libraries.
I tried below code to show/hide `<td>` in my table.

In my in my html :

```
<tr *ngFor="let new of RESULTDATA;let i = index">
 <td ngIf="i==SelectedIndex"><input type="textbox"></td>
```

I want to show couple of rows below(not beside) of which row is selected in my table. give me suggestions

Comment: u can try using bootstrap accordians.

Comment: how can i i.e i am not getting static table and static rows

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let new of RESULTDATA; let i = index;">
    <span *ngIf="i === indexOfClickedRow">
        <td><button (click)="indexOfClickedRow = i">click me</button></td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </span>
</tr>
```

And don't forget to declare `indexOfClickedRow` in your component.

By doing this, clicking on a button will hide all the other rows.

Comment: should i initialize `indexOfClickedRow =0`

Comment: no, just declare it, like `indexOfClickedRow: number;`

Comment: if i don't declare `indexOfClickedRow =0` `<span>is in hide mode

Comment: No, if you don't declare it, you have an error saying indexOfClickedRow is unknown. If you **initialize** it to 0, then it will only show the first row (because if it's equal to 0, then it will only show the row where i = 0).

Comment: i created one plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/du34mbmQ8qaAF44QS5kE?p=preview)

Comment: You had to change the condition too, sorry : [here is the plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/BYvGEuQOdQn8ApPhq95H?p=preview)

Comment: please open the link which i posted in my question or see this[link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/igniteuisamples/jsfiddle-samples/tree/master/EN/HtmlSamples/hierarchical-grid/angular/) .tell me some suggestions